# Spring ListableBeanFactory performance

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using [ListableBeanFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansWithAnnotation-java.lang.Class-) to fetch beans that match specific annotations. While this works, the performance is low. Also, I also know the set of classes which will contain the annotations. It seems the ListableBeanFactory is searching all the beans. How do I tell it to search only a small subset of classes so that I can improve the performance?

Comment: What is the actual implementation class?

Comment: @meskobalazs I have Autowired it. The class name at runtime appears to be org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking this spring feature does not perform well in the real-time repeating tasks. Try to fetch these annotated beans during the startup and then access them. Or just don't use Spring for this particular case. Another way is to use child context instead of main Spring context: you can create additional child context containing beans from the specific package or just the specific beans, they will still be able to resolve their dependencies from parent context but not vice versa.